# Perl: Replace multiple strings in text line with foreach loop and substitute

Tags: perl, foreach, substitution

This is my goal:

1. Find specific files and save

   a) foldername

   b) filename with full path
2. For each file, use the file name and folder name to replace two text strings in a file and write the result to an array (later to a file)

but I am obviously missing something because my foreach loop is not working.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use diagnostics;
use File::Find::Rule;
use File::Spec;
use File::Basename;
use Cwd;
my $dir = cwd;
my $command_template = 'Here is my Filepath: file and this is the Folderpath: folder';
my $search_file = 'test.txt';
my @files = File::Find::Rule->file()
                ->name($search_file)
                #->maxdepth(2)
                ->in($dir);
my @command_files;
foreach (@files){
    my $directories = dirname ($_);
    $command_template =~ s/file/$_/g;
    $command_template =~ s/folder/$directories/g;
    push(@command_files,$command_template,"\n");
}
print "@command_files";
open COMMAND_FILES, '>command_files.txt' or die "Can't open COMMAND_FILES: $!\n";
print COMMAND_FILES @command_files;
```

The problem is here:

```
foreach (@files){
        my $directories = dirname ($_);
        $command_template =~ s/filepath/$_/g;
        $command_template =~ s/folder/$directories/g;
        push(@command_files,$command_template,"\n");
    }
```

if I set

```
@files = qw/ c:\1\test.txt c:\2\test.txt c:\2\1\test.txt /;
```

but all that is written to @command_files:

```
Here is my Filepath: c:\1\test.txt and this is the Folderpath: c:\1
Here is my Filepath: c:\1\test.txt and this is the Folderpath: c:\1
Here is my Filepath: c:\1\test.txt and this is the Folderpath: c:\1
```

I want:

```
Here is my Filepath: c:\1\test.txt and this is the Folderpath: c:\1
Here is my Filepath: c:\2\test.txt and this is the Folderpath: c:\2
Here is my Filepath: c:\2\1\test.txt and this is the Folderpath: c:\2\1
```

Why is the foreach loop only bringing the first content in array @files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You modify `$command_template` with your substitution. The second time through the loop it doesn't match.

Make a copy of `$command_template` inside the loop and then do `$copy =~ s/filepath/$_/g`.